# C#: Program flow: I can't find the answer despite knowing that it is obviously easy

Tags: c#

I tend to figure most things out on my own but for the life of me I can't figure a professional way of doing this despite quite the search.

Here is my basic program:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{ 
class MonsterAttackRolls
     {
    public int GoblinAttack()
    {
        int AttackNumber = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
       AttackNumber = rnd.Next(1, 21);
        return(AttackNumber);            
    }

    public int OrcAttack()
    {
        int AttackNumber = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        AttackNumber = rnd.Next(11, 31);
        return (AttackNumber);
    }

    public int OgreAttack()
    {
        int AttackNumber = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        AttackNumber = rnd.Next(21, 41);
        return (AttackNumber);
    }

}

class ApplicationObject
{
    static void Main()
    {
      MonsterAttackRolls Goblin1 = new MonsterAttackRolls();
      MonsterAttackRolls Orc1 = new MonsterAttackRolls();
      MonsterAttackRolls Ogre1 = new MonsterAttackRolls();

        Console.WriteLine("These are the attack numbers for the Goblin and the Orc! {0} {1}", Goblin1.GoblinAttack(), Orc1.OrcAttack());
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("This is the Ogre's attack number! {0}", Ogre1.OgreAttack());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Now I want to return back to my Main() program and move straight into the Ogre's attack.  How do i do that?  With a goto?  Lol, I have no clue.

Comment: What do you mean by "return back to my Main() program?"  Do you mean you want to go around the code in `Main` again?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear.  How do I get back to my main program after calling the function?  As in, the program lists my random numbers for Orc and Goblin but then the program ends.

Comment: Is your problem because you're reading line? It won't return to your Main() until you hit enter on the ReadLine command

Comment: Do you want to call Main method recursively?

Comment: OMG...yeah.  All I had to do was hit enter.  Wow, that was a huge waste of 2 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Question answered.  How do I delete my question here or check it as answered?

Comment: In each class you create Random: `Random rnd = new Random();` This is incorrect. You should initialize Random once and reuse it. Otherwise Random is always initialized by current-time-derived value and your rnd.Next will produce not-so-random values. Just try to output several `Goblin1.GoblinAttack()`'s in a row.

Comment: Thanks Artemix.  I've never programmed in my life:  I bought Illustrated C# 2012 4th Ed (Solis) 3 days ago so I'm just learning the bare basics at the moment.  

Today's lesson was my first user-defined type: classes.  Didn't realize I just had to hit enter to continue my program. Sigh. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is just to hit enter after each ReadLine as it's waiting for your input.

Oh and I think this is a really cool first program to write, much cooler than "Hello World"... swing for the fences ye mighty Ogres ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a loop with correct conditions otherwise your program will run from start to finish once and then exit. 
If you want your ogre to attack a certain number of times put it in a for loop e.g:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

  attack code here;

}
```

I would suggest adding some user input to dictate program flow? Also think about putting monsters into their own class e.g have a main Moster Class with all shared attributes you will need for a montser and then set each monster as a derived class.

You can then set up your attack method to accept type of monster. Should prevent you having to write an attack method for each monster.

Answer (score 0):

You program ends after printing output because you get to the end of your `Main` mnethod, and that method *is*, to all intents and purposes, your program.  In order to make it repeat the process you've already done, you need a **loop**.

There are several ways of looping in C#.  You can loop a fixed number of times using a `for` loop, or you can loop while a condition is true using a `while` or `do` loop.  For example, if you wanted to repeat your process ten times, you could use this in your main loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
{
    // put your original code here
}
```